# ASP.NET C# How to Select List Item by Text dynamically through string retrieved from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, listitem

i have a string which takes value from Dataset ds

```
string maritalStatus = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["maritalStatus"].toString();
```

Now how can i select that list item from text value dynamically.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMaritalStatus" runat="server"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMaritalStatus_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Text="Single" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Divorced" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Separated" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Widowed" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
```

I have to do this for many other dropdown as well. And the value of some are not in serial order. I tried

```
ddlMaritalStatus.SelectedItem.Text = maritalStatus;
```

but this code is not working. All it does to change the text only of the selected List Item i.e "Single" to the text that is coming from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to map the possible values to a dictionary as the Value of this items are integers, something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> statusMap = new Dictionary<string, int>(),

statusMap.Add("Single", 0);
statusMap.Add("Divorced", 1);
//And so on..
```

Then you can set the SelectedValue of the DropDown:

```
ddlMaritalStatus.SelectedValue = statusMap[maritalStatus].ToString();
```

Comment: For Some dropdownlist i have 50 -52 list items. So i have to make Dictionary for them. :( Is there another way?

Comment: If you set the Value of the listitems the same as the text of the database then you can assign it directly.

Comment: Thanks @Gusman but the values are quite messed up and not in serial. I wanted to select list item just by using text.

Comment: Ehm.. that's what I meant, you have your items defined like *<asp:ListItem Text="Single" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>* if they were like *<asp:ListItem Text="Single" Value="Single"></asp:ListItem>* then you can set the string which comes from the db.

Comment: Ok my bad. Sorry @Gusman. I misunderstood. I always thought value can only be integer. How silly am i ? :D

Comment: Hehehehe, no problem, to program is to learn something new each day :)

Comment: If you change the items definitions then *ddlMaritalStatus.SelectedValue = maritalStatus;* will be more than enough.